# JavaScript calling something that I didn't call?

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

So I got a ReferenceError in my JS file. I thought that I must have typed something wrong but I didn't. JS seems to be calling something by itself. I've tried loading the file at the top and the bottom of the HTML document, both threw an error. Heres the error:

```js
ReferenceError: rl is not defined at /breadcrumb.js:36:34
```

Here's lines 34 and 35, as there is no line 36:

```js
element = "<li class='breadcrumb-item active'>" + url[-1] + "</li>";
$(".breadcrumb").append(element);
```

Can someone tell me why it's calling "rl"? Maybe "u" changes something when I call `url[-1]`? Thanks

Comment: Hi ! Can you make a stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery) with your code in it ?

Comment: I can't figure out how to share it. When i hit the share button it brings me to links that dont have the project

Comment: Search for stackblitz jquerry, you will find a blank jquery project. You can put your code in it

Comment: It says this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-uvvbp9 but that link dodsnt work for me. Also the error is now `ReferenceError: rl is not defined
    at /breadcrumb.js:41:34` after bug fixes

Comment: I think i found the problem. My editor decided that it was time to put 30 lines of invisible code at the end of the file and not show me. It just appeared and the first line it added referenced rl